# How to reset global variable in a subsequent import

Tags: python, global-variables, globalization

I have 3 modules.

*a.py*

global _message
def somefunc():
...#update _message
...print (_message)

*b.py*

import a
def someotherfunc():
...return None

*c.py*

def corefunc():

...import b
...for m in n:
......#do some steps
......if _message:
.........do some more

My problem is... because _message is global, there is a residual value per iteration in c.py.

How do I cleanup _message for each iteration in c.py?